# S3 signing of browser POST commands in Elixir

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, elixir

I'm trying to work through the [S3 signing example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html). But I'm not getting the interim answers in their docs. I started in `iex` with:

```
policy = %{"conditions"=> [
        %{"bucket"=> "sigv4examplebucket"},
        ["starts-with", "$key", "user/user1/"],
        %{"acl"=> "public-read"},
        %{"success_action_redirect"=> "http=>//sigv4examplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html"},
        ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image/"],
        %{"x-amz-meta-uuid"=> "14365123651274"},
        %{"x-amz-server-side-encryption"=> "AES256"},
        ["starts-with", "$x-amz-meta-tag", ""],
        %{"x-amz-credential"=> "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE/20151229/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request"},
        %{"x-amz-algorithm"=> "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"},
        %{"x-amz-date"=> "20151229T000000Z"}
      ]
    }

stringToSign = policy |> Poison.encode! |> Base.encode64
```

But the `stringToSign` comes out rather shorter than the Amazon example.

For the signature I have these helpers:

```
@secret_key "wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY"

def signing_key2(secret, date, region, service) do
    hash_sha256("AWS4" <> secret, date)
    |> hash_sha256(region)
    |> hash_sha256(service)
    |> hash_sha256("aws4_request")
end

def hash_sha256(secret, msg) do
  hash_sha256_bis(secret, msg)
  |> Base.url_encode64
end

def hash_sha256_bis(secret, msg) do
  :crypto.hmac(:sha256, secret, msg)
end
```

and ran

```
signing_key2(@secret_key, "20151229", "us-east-1", "s3")
```

but this came out shorter than the test answer. Would welcome some pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the derived key incorrectly. You should not be base64 encoding the intermediate hmac results.

Only the hmac of the actual string to sign needs any encoding and that just needs to be output in base 16 (via `Base.encode16(case: :lower)`

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. I've now got a string the same length, but with capitals and where making it lower case is not going to be enough. Will relook at my code though

Comment: It seems to work, but now I'm surprised as, when i reread the instructions, it talks about hex encoding the final signature and that does not work (result is too short)

Answer (score 1):

If you decode the base64 string from amazon's example, you'll note that they are using \r\n as newline character:

```
iex(25)> Base.decode64("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")
{:ok,
 "{ \"expiration\": \"2015-12-30T12:00:00.000Z\",\r\n  \"conditions\": [\r\n    {\"bucket\": \"sigv4examplebucket\"},\r\n    [\"starts-with\", \"$key\", \"user/user1/\"],\r\n    {\"acl\": \"public-read\"},\r\n    {\"success_action_redirect\": \"http://sigv4examplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html\"},\r\n    [\"starts-with\", \"$Content-Type\", \"image/\"],\r\n    {\"x-amz-meta-uuid\": \"14365123651274\"},\r\n    {\"x-amz-server-side-encryption\": \"AES256\"},\r\n    [\"starts-with\", \"$x-amz-meta-tag\", \"\"],\r\n\r\n    {\"x-amz-credential\": \"AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE/20151229/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request\"},\r\n    {\"x-amz-algorithm\": \"AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\"},\r\n    {\"x-amz-date\": \"20151229T000000Z\" }\r\n  ]\r\n}"}
```

Also note the double newline in there, which you will not get from Poison either. In order to get the exact same base64 result, you can do:

```
s = ~s({ "expiration": "2015-12-30T12:00:00.000Z",
  "conditions": [
    {"bucket": "sigv4examplebucket"},
    ["starts-with", "$key", "user/user1/"],
    {"acl": "public-read"},
    {"success_action_redirect": "http://sigv4examplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html"},
    ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image/"],
    {"x-amz-meta-uuid": "14365123651274"},
    {"x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"},
    ["starts-with", "$x-amz-meta-tag", ""],

    {"x-amz-credential": "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE/20151229/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request"},
    {"x-amz-algorithm": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"},
    {"x-amz-date": "20151229T000000Z" }
  ]
})
iex(24)> s |> String.replace("\n", "\r\n") |> Base.encode64
"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"
```

Not so sure how to calculate the final signature but this explains the different values for the encoded base64 string.

Comment: Thanks. I'm a bit worried how sensitive this all is to silly things like carriage returns!